# What is represents this class diagram in Java code?

Tags: class, service, uml, payment, diagram

What is represents this diagram in Java code ?

Also, what about modifiers they are have default value 
or this is dependes to language (Java - package, C++ - private ) ?

Now, I guess this and have no idea about meaning of {disjoint, complete}:

---

```
    class PaymentService {
      private List<Payment>;
    }

    class Payment {
      private int amount; // f.e. int
      private PaymentService unnamedPaymentService;
      private Customer unnamedCustomer;
    }

    class Customer {
      private List<Payment>;
    }

    class MileagePayment extends Payment {
      // and so on
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: What is wrong in this question ? 
I wrote my supposes and formulate concrete question

Comment: It is possible to privent vote the already answered questions in StackOverFlow? Cause we have bad peoples that can rendomly vote down your topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram and java code match up reasonably well.

The diagram has no information about modifiers, there is nothing to suggest privacy or encapsulation of data.

{disjoint} means that it can only be one or the other. You cannot have an instance of Cash Payment that is also instance of a Mileage Payment for example. I wouldn't worry too much about it in terms of reverse engineering.

Comment: Yes, it seems I got it, it is means mutually exclusions, but now I have no idea when it will not so.I mean how it possible to mix to objects, it is probably just logical idea

Comment: you could have a student and teacher that extend from person. You could have a person who is both a student and a teacher. So in that situation it would not be mutually exclusive.